# IE9: Weird Javascript error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, adsense

I am getting an error while trying to display Google DFP ad banners in my website. The ads are showing in all browsers except IE9. You can view a simple test page with the banner here: (demo taken offline). The error is "Exception thrown and not caught" (google_ads.js, line 34 char 474).

I **can** view the ad in IE9 if I switch to IE7/8 compatibility view, so the problem appears to be with IE9. I am not sure if this is restricted to my computer, or if this is a universal problem. If it's the latter, this is a very serious concern for anybody running Google ads!

*Your ads might not be showing on any of the newer computers with IE9 installed*!

Can somebody please have a look, and confirm if this is a Google issue, or an issue with the my code?

Wild Thing

Comment: Do you have a repro URL? I haven't seen any problems here.

Comment: Hi Eric, you can see the HTML here: http://pastebin.com/1i9Z636e. Keep in mind that this is a live DFP account, so please don't click on the ads. The version of IE9 I tested against was 9.0.7930.16406.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't really find a permanent solution, but if anybody runs across this problem, you can just add

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

in your header to force your browser to emulate the IE8 document mode. This seems to fix the JS errors as well.

Comment: This will not work for all situations. I [found a bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347857/how-do-i-convert-enter-to-tab-with-focus-change-in-ie9-it-worked-in-ie8) where IE9 does not allow you to update event.keyCode in js. Switching to IE8 document mode through developer tools fixed it, but adding this header did not work, so there's more to it than that.

Comment: I see. I'm sure Google would've updated support for their ad platform for IE9, so I will do another test to see if my site supports IE9 perfectly.