# Jquery select NEXT text field on Enter Key Press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard

I have made a page using jquery, and on load it selects the first text field automatically. I want it to then move to the next field when the ENTER key is pressed.

```
$('.barcodeField input').bind('keyup', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode==13){
       $("this + input").focus();     
    }
});
```

I can't find anything that works on the net. And I've scoured the forums.

Comment: Interesting, because I answered a question just like this :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494552/change-enter-from-submission-to-tab/4494691#4494691.  Additionally, I'd advise against this, because users are used to using tab to go to another field instead of enter.

Comment: Yes I know this is a total no no when it comes to webpages, but this is for a Barcode mapping system using a barcode scanner, that writes to the screen in this format "," + barcode + "ENTER"

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664375/how-to-convert-an-enter-key-press-into-a-tab-key-press-for-web-pages/9333124#9333124) linking to this [example showing how to emulate enter as tab](http://joelpurra.github.com/plusastab/example/enter-as-tab.html). It's a reusable plugin called [PlusAsTab](http://joelpurra.github.com/plusastab/), using CSS classes or HTML5 `data-*` attributes to mark fields/forms/containers you want the functionality in.

Comment: There's an answer for this question using nextAll here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494552/change-enter-from-submission-to-tab/4494691#4494691

Answer (score 17):

I've created a little function which can do what you need. This is the version I use so you may need to change the class names but you should get the idea.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".vertical").keypress(function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 13) { 
        textboxes = $("input.vertical");
        debugger;
        currentBoxNumber = textboxes.index(this);
        if (textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1] != null) {
            nextBox = textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1]
            nextBox.focus();
            nextBox.select();
            event.preventDefault();
            return false 
            }
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

So basically:-

- Get all the input fields matching .vertical
- Find which is the current text box
- Find the next one
- Set the focus on that one

Comment: any idea on make circle if you reach end of input go to index 0 something like that?

Answer (score 11):

You should use:

```
$(this).next('input').focus();
```

Comment: This will work if the next sibling is an `<input>`, but if it's a `<label>` or something else, it won't find a match.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.enterNext = function(){
       var _i =0;
       $('input[type=text], select',this)
            .each(function(index){
            _i = index;
            $(this)
                .addClass('tab'+index)
                .keydown(function(event){
                    if(event.keyCode==13){
                        $('.tab'+(index+1)).focus();
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });

        })
     $( "input[type=submit]",this ).addClass('tab'+(_i+1));
}})(jQuery);
```

for use:

```
$('form.element').enterNext();
```

---

in my case this is the best solution in that I got because the function .next() is strict with elements outside their branch DOM.
The best way is to force an index.

and sorry for my bad English...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just need top have the DOM elements in some structure so that you can select the next one.  I'd suggest exploiting tabindex, but anything that let's you have a defined order will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with. The issue I had was that I needed to maintain tabindex, i.e. it had to function exactly that same as hitting tab. It uses both underscore and jquery.

I've left in my debugging code:

```
try {
    var inputs = $("input[id^=tpVal-]");
    var sortedInputs = _.sortBy(inputs, function(element){
        var tabIndex = $(element).attr('tabindex');//debugging
        var id = $(element).attr('id');//debugging
        console.log(id +" | "+ tabIndex +" | "+ $(element));//debugging
        return parseInt($(element).attr('tabindex'));
    });
    $(sortedInputs).each(function (index, element) {
        $(element).keyup(function(event){
            if(event.keyCode==13) {
                var $thisElement = $(element);//debugging
                var nextIndex = index+1;//debugging
                var $nextElement = $(sortedInputs[nextIndex]);
                var thisId = $thisElement.attr('id');//debugging
                var nextId = $nextElement.attr('id');//debugging
                console.log("Advance from "+thisId+" to "+nextId);//debugging
                if($nextElement!=undefined) {
                    $(sortedInputs[index + 1]).focus();
                }
            }
        });
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="122" class='TabOnEnter' tabindex="1" /><br>
        <input id="123" class='TabOnEnter' tabindex="2" /><br>

         <input type="text" name="abc" /><br>
          <input type="text" name="abc1" /><br>
           <input type="text" name="abc2" /><br>
           <input type="text" name="abc3" class='TabOnEnter' tabindex="3" /><br>

        <input  class='TabOnEnter' tabindex="4" /><br>
        <input  class='TabOnEnter' tabindex="5" /><br>
        <input  class='TabOnEnter' tabindex="6" /><br>
<!--        <textarea class='TabOnEnter' tabindex="6">Hi, I am a test area</textarea>-->
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class='TabOnEnter' tabindex="7">


         <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on("keypress", ".TabOnEnter", function (e)
            {
                //Only do something when the user presses enter
                if (e.keyCode == 13)
                {
                    var nextElement = $('[tabindex="' + (this.tabIndex + 1) + '"]');
                    console.log(this, nextElement);
                    if (nextElement.length)
                        nextElement.focus()
                    else
                        $('[tabindex="1"]').focus();
                }
            });

//Hidden inputs should get their tabindex fixed, not in scope ;)
//$(function(){ $('input[tabindex="4"]').fadeOut();  })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3"> Name </div>
<div class="col-md-3"> <input type="text" /> </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3"> Email</div>
<div class="col-md-3"> <input type="email" /> </div>
</div>
```

Jquery code:

```
 $(document).on('keypress', 'input,select', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().parent().next('div').find('input').focus();
    }
  });
```

Comment: This won't work if the next input is anything other than an `input` element.