# Enter Key as Tab and Move Focus to next Control in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change Enter from submission to Tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494552/change-enter-from-submission-to-tab)

Hi Experts
 How to override tab key with enter key in asp.net web form and move to next control on enter key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example I found.  It's not the prettiest code, but it seems to do the job.  http://www.latentmotion.com/downloads/enter-to-tab.html