# How do you skip over hidden fields when using enter key as a tab in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, internet-explorer-11

I have a asp.net web application that is being developed for IE11 and I am trying to have the Enter key function the same as the Tab key. Most of the time it works fine with the code below. However if there are fields that are disabled or in a div that is hidden the Enter key does not advance to the next enabled and visible field.

Here is what i have:

I have the following on my main div so it applies to all text boxes:
onkeydown="changeEnterToTab()

The functions fire properly but the getNextElement function returns a field that is not displayed or is disabled.

Any ideas?

```
    function changeEnterToTab() {
        var node = (event.target) ? event.target : ((event.srcElement) ? event.srcElement : null);
        if ((event.keyCode == 13) && ((node.type == "text") || (node.type == "radio"))) {
            getNextElements(node).focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    function getNextElement(field) {
        var form = field.form;
        for (var e = 0; e < form.elements.length; e++) {
            if (field == form.elements[e]) {
                e++;
                break;
            }
        }
        e++;
        debugger;
        while (form.elements[e % form.elements.length].type == "hidden") {
            e++;
        }
        return form.elements[e % form.elements.length];
    }
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but if you'd check `node === document.activeElement` after setting focus to `node`, you would find out if the current `node` is focusable. Then just recall `getNextElement` untill a focusable element will be found.

Comment: The activeElement is returning false for both the node that I am leaving and the node that I am trying to skip so that doesn't work.

Comment: [Seems to work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/dmp78/). My previous comment was maybe a bit poorly worded, `getNextElement` as it is can't be used. At the fiddle checking `activeElement` works fine, and hidden/disabled elements are not focused. Though I'd rather use `tabIndex`, and toggled it between -1 and 0, then it could be used to check the tabbing order in the keydown handler too.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your hidden controls at the top of the form so the user will only "tab" to the rest visible control.

<strike>You can exclude the control from the tab order by set its **tabIndex** to **-1**</strike>

```
<input type="text" name="username" tabIndex="-1" />
```

Comment: Though this is true, OP is emulating `TAB` with `ENTER` using JavaScript, hence the tabbing order is not used.

Comment: Well, just realized that. Edited :)

Comment: The hidden controls dynamically show/hide and enable/disable and are throughout the form itself so i cannot put them all at the top.

Comment: @Ben I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494552/change-enter-from-submission-to-tab

Answer (score 0):

I did not find an actual answer to this question but I got around the issue by reordering the TabIndex completely to handle the instances where the controls are hidden/disabled.

Thanks for the ideas though guys.