# Issues with IE9 with javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

In all the modern browsers except in IE9 my code is working, but in IE9 it is not getting into my for loop. Please help me in understanding what is going wrong. Thanks.

```
for(var i=0; i<jobs.length; i++)ß is causing the issue.
      {
          tmp[jobs[i]['id']] =
          {
              'jobTitle' : jobs[i]['jobTitle'],
              'brand' : jobs[i]['brand'],
              'pid' : jobs[i]['pid'],
              'dynaURL' : jobs[i]['dynaURL']
          };
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the website to the Compatibilty View.

Or, you can change it from Developer Tools:
Tools-> F12 Developer Tools -> Check here the Browser Mode and Document Mode

you can check also similar issue:
[IE9: Weird Javascript error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251625/ie9-weird-javascript-error?rq=1)